Cannot install gazeb_ros_pkgs from source due to protobuf incompatibility
I'm trying to install gazebo_ros from gazebo_ros_pkgs. I'm using Ros2 humble and gazebo-11.11. I'm working on a Lambda and I have to install everything from source. The gazebo was already installed and according to this command using protobuf 3.17: ldd /usr/bin/gazebo | grep protobuf
libprotobuf.so.17 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.17 (0x00007f62b7fae000)
I tried to install gazebo_ros_pkgs using 3.17 but this didn't work because some functions were not the same for the gazebo installation and the protobuf. I looked at the github of protobuf and the functions from gazebo that corresponded to the same functions in protobuf were in version 3.6. However, when I try to install with protobuf 3.6 I get this error:/usr/include/gazebo-11/gazebo/msgs/world_modify.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
12 | #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
|  ^~~~~
/usr/include/gazebo-11/gazebo/msgs/world_modify.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
13 | #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
|  ^~~~~
I managed to build gazebo_ros_pkgs with protoc --version = 3.6 and protobuf 5.27. However, if I want to use gazebo I need to have these two aligned, because I get this error: [libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:120] File already exists in database:
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1356] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
what(): CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size):
That's why I want to reinstall everything.
I'm using linux Ubuntu 20.04.

Please use code formatting for errors and console output
